# JSP Ajax Post to another JSP Page

Tags: jsp, jquery

I have the following in a jsp page;

```
<script language="javascript">
    function ClickMe_Click(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "dimensionList.jsp",
            data: "dimensionName=Slappy",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
            error: function(request,error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
<a href="." onclick="return ClickMe_Click() ;">Click Me</a>
```

In my **dimensionList.jsp** I have;

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    out.print("it works!");
%>
```

I am getting an error but when I alert out error I get **error** which is less than helpful.

Comment: are you sure you didn't put quotes in by accident? i.e. alert('error')?

Comment: @Gabriel, yeah pretty sure about that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ClickMe_Click(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "dimensionList.jsp",
        data: {"dimensionName":"Slappy"},
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.data);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }  
    });
    return false;
}
```

added the error function as specified below, to see what is going on,also fixed the data, you were missing **{}**

Comment: Made these changes but still getting "error" and the error message.

Comment: try with the new error block I added to see if you get the correct error information back; I posted the incorrect code the first time

Comment: Got this working now.  Turns out it was a 404.  had to change from dimensionList.jsp to dimensionList.htm

Answer (score 1):

Is that jquery?  It supports the error ajax event as well as success.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still stuck, try loading it up in Chrome, and before you click the button, click on Developer->Developer Tools, then click Scripts, and set a break point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ClickMe_Click(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "dimensionList.jsp",
        data: "dimensionName=Slappy",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting (any) alert within my success function what so ever.

Comment: I have made a correction now... Try alert(msg.data) instead of alert(msg)

Comment: there is an error being generated so we don't actually get into the success function